# increment a line according to the previous line

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, auto-increment

This is my table

```
id / step    / piece / tube / Validate / tool / tool2 / tool3 / index
__________________________________________________________________
1 / step3    /4113292/ ezpz / ok       /616255/222233/222231  / 0
2 / step6    /4113292/ ezpz /          /333255/212393/922231  / 0
3 / step2    /3322234/ PZEZ /          /321938/330200/3O32O   / 0
4 / step4    /4113292/ ezpz /          /616255/902233/8243231 / 0
```

I want to increment the index when I add a new step(with an insert) who has the same tube and piece.

for exemple:

```
id / step    / piece / tube / Validate / tool / tool2 / tool3 / index
__________________________________________________________________
1 / step3    /4113292/ ezpz / ok       /616255/222233/222231  / 1
2 / step6    /4113292/ ezpz /          /333255/212393/922231  / 2
3 / step2    /3322234/ PZEZ /          /321938/330200/3O32O   / 1
4 / step4    /4113292/ ezpz /          /616255/902233/8243231 / 3
```

and if I add a new step for piece 4113292 and tube ezpz I want this :

```
id / step    / piece / tube / Validate / tool / tool2 / tool3 / index
__________________________________________________________________
1 / step3    /4113292/ ezpz / ok       /616255/222233/222231  / 1
2 / step6    /4113292/ ezpz /          /333255/212393/922231  / 2
3 / step2    /3322234/ PZEZ /          /321938/330200/3O32O   / 1
4 / step4    /4113292/ ezpz /          /616255/902233/8243231 / 3
5 / step7    /4113292/ ezpz /          /616255/902233/8243231 / 4
```

or if I add a new step for the piece 3322234

```
id / step    / piece / tube / Validate / tool / tool2 / tool3 / index
__________________________________________________________________
1 / step3    /4113292/ ezpz / ok       /616255/222233/222231  / 1
2 / step6    /4113292/ ezpz /          /333255/212393/922231  / 2
3 / step2    /3322234/ PZEZ /          /321938/330200/3O32O   / 1
4 / step4    /4113292/ ezpz /          /616255/902233/8243231 / 3
5 / step1    /3322234/ PZEZ /          /432938/330200/3O32O   / 2
```

i do that cause when a step is ok I want to go to the next step

Comment: I don't see any php nor mysql but you tagged your question with that

Comment: sry I'll change

Comment: You are aware that you can define an AUTO INCREMENT field in MySQL?

Comment: but I can't define two auto increment in my table and It's not rly an auto increment I want for my index .

Comment: the next step = index of the last step + 1 (for the same piece)

Comment: Please add an example of your INSERT statement. I feel this can be done with a trigger.

Comment: INSERT INTO operation (step, piece, tube, tool,tool2,3,index)
VALUES (step3, 4113292, ezpz,616255,902233,8243231, ?);

Comment: for the index part I dont know what can I do I want to select the last step added and increment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example insert from user - instead a "?" put "0" as default value, because every first insert will be 0.

```
INSERT INTO operation (step, piece, tube, tool,tool2,3,index) VALUES (step3, 4113292, ezpz,616255,902233,8243231, 0);
```

When you do an insert again with same piece and tube, this trigger should do the job.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER yourTrigger
BEFORE INSERT
   ON yourTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE maxIndex INT DEFAULT -1;
    SELECT MAX(index1) m
        FROM yourTable
        WHERE piece = NEW.piece
            AND tube = NEW.tube
        INTO maxIndex;
    IF maxIndex >= 0 THEN
        SET NEW.index1 = maxIndex + 1;
    END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER;
```

Tested in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49210e/1).

P.S. I had to rename "index" to "index1" because SQL Fiddle doesn't work with column named "index".

Comment: it work on the fiddle but I have an error on mysql #1064 - error syntax ''  line 5

Comment: What line is that? Try with delimiter.

Comment: it's the var maxindex I can't declare "DECLARE maxIndex INT DEFAULT -1"

Comment: Try with delimiter and if it's the same, try with "integer" instead "INT".

Comment: change int to integer change nothing but I tried with "/" instead ";" and now the error is around line 6

Comment: what is the utility of the "m" after "max(index1)"?

Comment: with the delimiter I got this #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: Do you "drop trigger yourTrigger" before creating one? "m" is just an alias, maybe it's not needed at all.

Comment: I did that but I have an error at the insert DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS yourTrigger//
CREATE TRIGGER yourTrigger
BEFORE INSERT
   ON yourTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE maxIndex INT DEFAULT -1;
    SELECT MAX(index1) m
        FROM yourTable
        WHERE piece = NEW.piece
            AND tube = NEW.tube
        INTO maxIndex;
    IF maxIndex >= 0 THEN
        SET NEW.index1 = maxIndex + 1;
    END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER;
INSERT INTO operation (step, piece, tube, tool,tool2,3,index) VALUES (step3, 4113292, ezpz,616255,902233,8243231, 0);

Comment: you must change "index1" to "index" and "yourTable" to your real table name where you are doing inserts.

Comment: i create a fake table named yourTable for the test

Comment: it work it' was because of the space after the delimiter  thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a "data_event" table like this :

```
id / step    / piece / tube / Validate / tool / tool2 / tool3 / index
_____________________________________________________________________
1 / step3    /4113292/ ezpz / ok       /616255/222233/222231  / 1    
2 / step6    /4113292/ ezpz /          /333255/212393/922231  / 1    
2 / step6    /4113292/ ezpz /          /333255/212393/922231  / 1    
3 / step2    /3322234/ PZEZ /          /321938/330200/3O32O   / 1    
4 / step4    /4113292/ ezpz /          /616255/902233/8243231 / 1    
4 / step4    /4113292/ ezpz /          /616255/902233/8243231 / 1    
4 / step4    /4113292/ ezpz /          /616255/902233/8243231 / 1    
5 / step1    /3322234/ PZEZ /          /432938/330200/3O32O   / 1    
5 / step1    /3322234/ PZEZ /          /432938/330200/3O32O   / 1
```

Use this table "table_event" for insert (or delete) data (always with index=1)

```
create view data_aggregate as
select
    id,step,piece,tube,Validate,tool,tool2,tool3,sum(index) as index
from
    data_event
group by
    id,step,piece,tube,Validate,tool,tool2,tool3

id / step    / piece / tube / Validate / tool / tool2 / tool3 / index 
______________________________________________________________________
1 / step3    /4113292/ ezpz / ok       /616255/222233/222231  / 1     
2 / step6    /4113292/ ezpz /          /333255/212393/922231  / 2     
3 / step2    /3322234/ PZEZ /          /321938/330200/3O32O   / 1     
4 / step4    /4113292/ ezpz /          /616255/902233/8243231 / 3
5 / step1    /3322234/ PZEZ /          /432938/330200/3O32O   / 2
```

Use this table for select

Sometimes (may be every day, every hour...) you can replace the content of table_event by the result of the view (using a transaction and an intermediate table) to compress storage